# Request to opensea api failing

Tags: node.js, request, request-promise, opensea

Im trying to retrieve a collection through opensea's graphql api using request-promise. Im sending a request with these params and in response i keep receiving status code 403. I've copied the params directly from the browser where it works fine using fetch.

```
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://api.opensea.io/graphql',
      headers: {
        Host: 'api.opensea.io',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        accept: '*/*',
        origin: 'https://opensea.io',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        referer: 'https://opensea.io/'
      },
      body: {
       id: 'collectionQuery',
       query: 'query collectionQuery(\n  $collection: CollectionSlug!\n  $collections: [CollectionSlug!]\n  $collectionQuery: String\n  $includeHiddenCollections: Boolean\n  $numericTraits: [TraitRangeType!]\n  $query: String\n  $sortAscending: Boolean\n  $sortBy: SearchSortBy\n  $stringTraits: [TraitInputType!]\n  $toggles: [SearchToggle!]\n  $showContextMenu: Boolean\n) {\n  collection(collection: $collection) {\n    isEditable\n    bannerImageUrl\n    name\n    description\n    imageUrl\n    relayId\n    representativeAsset {\n      assetContract {\n        openseaVersion\n        id\n      }\n      id\n    }\n    ...collection_url\n    ...CollectionHeader_data\n    id\n  }\n  assets: query {\n    ...AssetSearch_data_1bS60n\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetCardContent_asset on AssetType {\n  relayId\n  name\n  ...AssetMedia_asset\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    openseaVersion\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n  collection {\n    slug\n    id\n  }\n  isDelisted\n}\n\nfragment AssetCardContent_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\n  assetQuantities(first: 18) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        asset {\n          relayId\n          ...AssetMedia_asset\n          id\n        }\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetCardFooter_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\n  name\n  assetCount\n  assetQuantities(first: 18) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        asset {\n          collection {\n            name\n            relayId\n            isVerified\n            ...collection_url\n            id\n          }\n          id\n        }\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  assetEventData {\n    lastSale {\n      unitPriceQuantity {\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  orderData {\n    bestBid {\n      orderType\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n    bestAsk {\n      closedAt\n      orderType\n      dutchAuctionFinalPrice\n      openedAt\n      priceFnEndedAt\n      quantity\n      decimals\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\n        quantity\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetCardFooter_asset_2V84VL on AssetType {\n  name\n  tokenId\n  collection {\n    name\n    isVerified\n    ...collection_url\n    id\n  }\n  hasUnlockableContent\n  isDelisted\n  isFrozen\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    openseaVersion\n    id\n  }\n  assetEventData {\n    firstTransfer {\n      timestamp\n    }\n    lastSale {\n      unitPriceQuantity {\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  decimals\n  orderData {\n    bestBid {\n      orderType\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n    bestAsk {\n      closedAt\n      orderType\n      dutchAuctionFinalPrice\n      openedAt\n      priceFnEndedAt\n      quantity\n      decimals\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\n        quantity\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetCardHeader_data_27d9G3 on AssetType {\n  relayId\n  favoritesCount\n  isDelisted\n  isFavorite\n  ...AssetContextMenu_data_3z4lq0 @include(if: $showContextMenu)\n}\n\nfragment AssetContextMenu_data_3z4lq0 on AssetType {\n  ...asset_edit_url\n  ...asset_url\n  ...itemEvents_data\n  isDelisted\n  isEditable {\n    value\n    reason\n  }\n  isListable\n  ownership(identity: {}) {\n    isPrivate\n    quantity\n  }\n  creator {\n    address\n    id\n  }\n  collection {\n    isAuthorizedEditor\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetMedia_asset on AssetType {\n  animationUrl\n  backgroundColor\n  collection {\n    displayData {\n      cardDisplayStyle\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  isDelisted\n  displayImageUrl\n}\n\nfragment AssetQuantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\n  asset {\n    ...Price_data\n    id\n  }\n  quantity\n}\n\nfragment AssetSearchFilter_data_1GloFv on Query {\n  ...CollectionFilter_data_tXjHb\n  collection(collection: $collection) {\n    numericTraits {\n      key\n      value {\n        max\n        min\n      }\n      ...NumericTraitFilter_data\n    }\n    stringTraits {\n      key\n      ...StringTraitFilter_data\n    }\n    id\n  }\n  ...PaymentFilter_data_2YoIWt\n}\n\nfragment AssetSearchList_data_gVyhu on SearchResultType {\n  asset {\n    assetContract {\n      address\n      chain\n      id\n    }\n    collection {\n      isVerified\n      id\n    }\n    relayId\n    tokenId\n    ...AssetSelectionItem_data\n    ...asset_url\n    id\n  }\n  assetBundle {\n    relayId\n    id\n  }\n  ...Asset_data_gVyhu\n}\n\nfragment AssetSearch_data_1bS60n on Query {\n  ...CollectionHeadMetadata_data_2YoIWt\n  ...AssetSearchFilter_data_1GloFv\n  ...SearchPills_data_2Kg4Sq\n  search(collections: $collections, first: 32, numericTraits: $numericTraits, querystring: $query, resultType: ASSETS, sortAscending: $sortAscending, sortBy: $sortBy, stringTraits: $stringTraits, toggles: $toggles) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        ...AssetSearchList_data_gVyhu\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    totalCount\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AssetSelectionItem_data on AssetType {\n  backgroundColor\n  collection {\n    displayData {\n      cardDisplayStyle\n    }\n    imageUrl\n    id\n  }\n  imageUrl\n  name\n  relayId\n}\n\nfragment Asset_data_gVyhu on SearchResultType {\n  asset {\n    isDelisted\n    ...AssetCardHeader_data_27d9G3\n    ...AssetCardContent_asset\n    ...AssetCardFooter_asset_2V84VL\n    ...AssetMedia_asset\n    ...asset_url\n    ...itemEvents_data\n    id\n  }\n  assetBundle {\n    ...bundle_url\n    ...AssetCardContent_assetBundle\n    ...AssetCardFooter_assetBundle\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment CollectionFilter_data_tXjHb on Query {\n  selectedCollections: collections(first: 25, collections: $collections, includeHidden: true) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        assetCount\n        imageUrl\n        name\n        slug\n        isVerified\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  collections(first: 100, includeHidden: $includeHiddenCollections, query: $collectionQuery, sortBy: SEVEN_DAY_VOLUME) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        assetCount\n        imageUrl\n        name\n        slug\n        isVerified\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment CollectionHeadMetadata_data_2YoIWt on Query {\n  collection(collection: $collection) {\n    bannerImageUrl\n    description\n    imageUrl\n    name\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment CollectionHeader_data on CollectionType {\n  name\n  description\n  imageUrl\n  bannerImageUrl\n  ...CollectionStatsBar_data\n  ...SocialBar_data\n  ...verification_data\n}\n\nfragment CollectionModalContent_data on CollectionType {\n  description\n  imageUrl\n  name\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment CollectionStatsBar_data on CollectionType {\n  stats {\n    numOwners\n    totalSupply\n    totalVolume\n    id\n  }\n  slug\n  floorPrice\n}\n\nfragment NumericTraitFilter_data on NumericTraitTypePair {\n  key\n  value {\n    max\n    min\n  }\n}\n\nfragment PaymentFilter_data_2YoIWt on Query {\n  paymentAssets(first: 10) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        symbol\n        relayId\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      cursor\n    }\n    pageInfo {\n      endCursor\n      hasNextPage\n    }\n  }\n  PaymentFilter_collection: collection(collection: $collection) {\n    paymentAssets {\n      symbol\n      relayId\n      id\n    }\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Price_data on AssetType {\n  decimals\n  imageUrl\n  symbol\n  usdSpotPrice\n  assetContract {\n    blockExplorerLink\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment SearchPills_data_2Kg4Sq on Query {\n  selectedCollections: collections(first: 25, collections: $collections, includeHidden: true) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        imageUrl\n        name\n        slug\n        ...CollectionModalContent_data\n        id\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment SocialBar_data on CollectionType {\n  relayId\n  discordUrl\n  externalUrl\n  instagramUsername\n  mediumUsername\n  slug\n  telegramUrl\n  twitterUsername\n  ...collection_url\n}\n\nfragment StringTraitFilter_data on StringTraitType {\n  counts {\n    count\n    value\n  }\n  key\n}\n\nfragment asset_edit_url on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n  collection {\n    slug\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment asset_url on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n}\n\nfragment bundle_url on AssetBundleType {\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment collection_url on CollectionType {\n  slug\n}\n\nfragment itemEvents_data on AssetType {\n  assetContract {\n    address\n    chain\n    id\n  }\n  tokenId\n}\n\nfragment verification_data on CollectionType {\n  isMintable\n  isSafelisted\n  isVerified\n}\n',
       variables: {
        collection: 'beeple-special-edition',
        collections: ['beeple-special-edition'],
        collectionQuery: null,
        includeHiddenCollections: null,
        numericTraits: null,
        query: null,
        sortAscending: true,
        sortBy: 'PRICE',
        stringTraits: null,
        toggles: null,
        showContextMenu: true
    }
  }
```

This results in response status code 403 and in response body it says `error code: 1020`

Comment: Did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, OpenSea currently has CloudFlaire protecting their GraphQL endpoint which means it is not yet available to developers.
[This issue](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/issues/71) was submitted for it, but no response yet from OpenSea