# FetchError: invalid json response body at... > reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from the OpenSea API but keep getting the following error:

> FetchError: invalid json response body at
> https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?format=json&order_direction=desc&owner=0x0f91b5a27c51dcad415eafb190e8235e987dcdcb
> reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Here is my current code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?format=json&order_direction=desc&owner=0xc3b9d43afbb3dcc92e19703480f37070692494e1`)
  const data = await res.json()

  return { props: { data } }

}

const Page = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.assets.map(asset => (
        <p>{asset.id}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Comment: I don't see a call for `getServerSideProps()` .

Comment: @akitirk [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) is a method handled internally by the Next.js framework, you don't call it explicitly.

Comment: thanks @juliomalves

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately opensea does not allow such a request right now.

You get HTML response with 403 error (Forbidden) instead of json.

The similar question here:
[Request to opensea api failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095096/request-to-opensea-api-failing)

Answer (score 0):

The error is triggered because you are getting a HTML response instead of JSON. If you make the request from the browser you get a successful response, but why you get an error making it through server-side? I think it's because there is a missing header in the server-side request. Try to get the HTML by using `fetch.text()` instead of `fetch.json()` then look for the error or the page you are getting and the difference between browser and server-side headers.