# Heroku FetchError: invalid json response body at https://some-random-api.ml/meme reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, json, heroku, discord.js

I tried to add a function to generate random meme to my Discord bot running on Heroku, but every time I try running it, it just gives me this error: `FetchError: invalid json response body at https://some-random-api.ml/meme reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. I'm wondering if Heroku has something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095096/request-to-opensea-api-failing)? If not, is there a problem with my code (posted below):

```
const memes = require("random-memes");
const { randomHexColor } = require('../admin/colorgen.js');


module.exports = {
    name: 'meme',
    description: 'Never mind what the description is!',
    async execute(message, args, Discord, Client, bot) {
        memes.random().then(meme => {
            
            const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(randomHexColor())
            .setTitle(meme.caption)
            // .setURL(meme.image)
            .setDescription(`category: ${meme.category}`)
            .setImage(meme.image);
            
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed] });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the app that is doing the request has the permissions (keyword: CORS). When visiting the url `https://some-random-api.ml/meme` there is no `<` which is misleading since what I am seeing may be different what your application is seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API may have just been down at the time, I have run into the same error before. Try using a [`.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) after the `.then(... => { ... })` to handle the error and possibly debug.

```js
memes.random().then(meme => {
    console.log(meme)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

If you are still getting an error with the NPM package, try just sending a [node-fetch request](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#json) to `https://some-random-api.ml/meme` which is the API that `random-memes` uses ([source code](https://github.com/halitsever/random-memes/blob/main/src/lib/random.js#L5)).

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const response = await fetch('https://some-random-api.ml/meme');
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);
```

data should return something like

```json
{
  "id": number,
  "image": string,
  "caption": string,
  "category": string
}
```

Then you can go from there.

Comment: This works I guess it must’ve been down at the time. Thank you so much!